# Mongo RequestStart() .net driver 2.0

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've recently update .net driver from legacy to new 2.0.
In old driver there was method RequestStart().
I need to make sure that bunch of operation will be in the same connection.

Is there a way to do something like RequestStart in .net driver 2.0 ?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm in the same position. Thanks!

Comment: all I've found is this : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1102